# Symfony Cronjob command kills after less then 10 minutes

Tags: php, symfony, cron, cron-task

I use in Symfony a conjob as a maintenance task to sync two databases. After less then 10 minutes the task is killed and I cannot find the reason. I already increased the max_execution_time in the php.ini file but this does not help. Anyone some ideas?

`max_execution_time = 900`

The task is run from the command

```
class MaintenanceCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
```

Comment: No errors ? are you logging something in the command ?

Comment: Are you sure you edited correct `php.ini` from cli?

Comment: No there are no errors. Second I looked at the phpinfo.php and there also the 900 seconds is shown.

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo() display in a browser or with php info.php ?

php.ini must be change in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

not /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: Yes I double checked it my phpinfo() in the browser. I changed it in /usr/local/lib/php.ini also the url is shown in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

Have you check if the server was out of memory?
Check `dmesg` for messages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).